# Can Get/Set accessors of property to be in different interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, get, set

I want something like the next:

```
interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}

interface IRenamableObject : INamedObject
{
    string Name { set; }
}
```

In words, I want to create two interfaces, one of which contains get accessor for property and another - set accessor. Can I do this in C#?

(The code compiles but the compiler gives the following warning:)

> 'IRenamableObject.Name' hides inherited member 'INamedObject.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: That's one of the questions a compiler can answer best.

Comment: Maybe you should have an get; property in IRenamableObject also.

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can:

```
interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}

interface IRenamableObject : INamedObject
{
    new string Name { set; }
}

class SomeObject : IRenamableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set;  }
}

// usage:
IRenamableObject obj = new SomeObject();
obj.Name = "some name";
Console.WriteLine((obj as INamedObject).Name);
```

Is it a good idea? I wouldn't want it in my code. It seems to me that when you get oddities like this, perhaps it indicates that there is a design flaw somewhere. One indication is that you do get a warning that `Name` in one of the interfaces shadows the other, so you need the `new` keyword, which I typically feel is a workaround more than a solution.

Note that the interfaces can be completely decoupled from each other:

```
interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}

interface IRenamableObject
{
    string Name { set; }
}
```

This would remove the shadowing issue. It would also allow you to have an object with a `Name` property that is write-only which is also a tad strange...

Comment: Isn´t it enough with "class SomeObject :  IRenamableObject" or am I missing something?

Comment: @Glenn: you are correct. Also, it's not necessary for `IRenamableObject` to inherit `INamedObject`.

Comment: Disagree with the idea that _"[this] indicates that there is a design flaw somewhere."_ I have a perfectly valid use case - an interface that is meant entirely for `get`ting generic spatial info about two different types of objects, both of which can supply similar data for reading, but need very different sort of data for their own `set`up and internal ops. Having said that, mine is not arranged hierarchically as yours is (C->B->A); mine is instead (B implements A, C implements A) where A is the read-only interface. Nonetheless, a good answer.

Comment: about "It would also allow you to have an object with a Name property that is write-only which is also a tad strange...", there's this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke)

Answer (score 0):

The property defined in `IRenamableObject` will hide the one in `INamedObject`.
You need to use

```
interface IRenamableObject : INamedObject
{
    new string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have Get and Set properties in two different interfaces.

But, main question is *Why do you need it that way?*

it compiles, doesn't mean that it's a correct design.

```
interface INamedObject 
{     
    string Name { get; } 
}

interface IRenamableObject //: INamedObject No need to inherit
{     
    string Name { set; } 
}
```